# Entity Framework Complex LINQ Support

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I know that Entity Framework has some LINQ support problems (at least in comparison to its predecessor LINQ to SQL)...and usually I'm able to find a creative way of restructuring my LINQ query so that it's supported by EF and doesn't throw a

```
"Unable to create a constant value of type ..."
```

But this time I'm having trouble. As usual, the problem is related to complex joins. This time it's required for modeling some legacy data I'm working with.

I have a query for Offices (a simple POCO)

```
public IQueryable<Office> Offices
{
    get
    {
        IQueryable<Office> query = 
            from pn in _context.Locations
            where pn.Type == "Y"
            select new Office
            {
                Id = pn.Id  + 1000,
                Name = pn.Name,
            };

        query = query.Union(
            from r in _context.Resources
            where r.ResourceType == "L"
            select new Office
            {
                Id = r.ResourceId,
                Name = r.ResourceName,
            });

        return query;
    }
}
```

Then I have something else that has an Office property on it.

```
public IQueryable<ScheduleEntry> ScheduleEntries
{
    get
    {
        return 
            from pc in _context.CalendarEntries
            join o in this.Offices on pc.LocationId 
                equals o.Id into offices
            from office in offices.DefaultIfEmpty()
            let mainOffice = this.Offices.First()
            select new ScheduleEntry
            {
                Id = pc.CalendarId,
                StartDateTime = pc.StartDateTime ?? DateTime.MinValue,
                EndDateTime = pc.EndDateTime ?? DateTime.MinValue,
                Office = pc.LocationId == 0 ? mainOffice : office,
            };
    }
}
```

Please note, telling me to make it an enumerable defeats the purpose...so please don't advise that.

And so....doing `CalendarEntries.ToArray()` throws `"Unable to create a constant value of type Office"...`

Specifically the problem is the `let mainOffice = Offices.First()`. If I remove that logic, the query works fine. Any idea how to make this work with Entity Framework?

Thanks.

Comment: Wow. "Poor LINQ support?" I think you should edit out the emotion or risk having this question closed as subjective and argumentative. Stick to the point.

Comment: EF does not have poor linq support. It is NOT store dependant. Linq to sql is basically a SQL Server code generation whereas EF is a true ORM. That means calculated properties will only work if there is a way to do them in ANY datastore (not just SQL Server). This is not poor support, just generic data store support.

Comment: That sounds more like a threat than a suggestion. Fair enough though, I'm looking for help, not threats.

Comment: @Gats: I don't think using a products features is an adequate defense for its failures. Taking one step forward and two steps back is not a definition of success.

Comment: I don't see how it's a failure. IQueryable is a way to build a query before it is executed on a data store. This means if you put stuff in it that the data store can't do, it doesn't work. If you run ToList on any of your queries, you have full linq support as it's no longer dependant on the data store. I am not using its features, I'm giving you a reason why it is not a failure, but a trade off by design. The data stores are where the poor support is, not the framework.

Comment: Are you using .NET 4.0 or 3.5?

Comment: 4.0. 3.5 was even worse.

Comment: @Gats: I'm perfectly aware of the way an IQueryProvider works. To say that this is because of the way the data store works is inaccurate/incorrect. It's perfectly possible to execute the above kind of query in a VERY wide variety of ways, all data store independent. The FRAMEWORK is what cannot do it. If it's a tradeoff, the tradeoff is that the EF team decided they couldn't figure out how or didn't have enough time to do this. Considering the predecessor to EF could do this no problem, I do consider that a failure.

Comment: That's where you're wrong and where I'm objecting. Linq to SQL is not considered a predecessor to EF as far as Microsoft is concerned. They have a totally different set of objectives and you can not compare a framework that is totally database dependant with one that is totally database independant.

Comment: Understood, but I disagree. Saying the LINQ to SQL is not considered a predecessor to EF is like saying BinaryFormatter is not considered a predecessor to DataContractSerializer. They have overlapping functionality but are completely different technologies with a completely different set of objectives....BUT in the technology paths MS has chosen to pursue, we are left with but one maintained, supported solution. Even though I understand that EF has a different set of goals, it IS MS's intended successor to LINQ to SQL by sheer fact that MS does not support LINQ to SQL anymore.

Comment: @Jeff: not a threat at all. I just voted to close. As far as I'm concerned, I'd welcome a question from you which had nothing to do with your emotions about Entity Framework.

Comment: They were parallel. Linq to SQL was a quick to market product to fill a short term need. EF development started at the same time and was always meant to be the big long term solution. Linq 2 SQL was always a stop gap despite the rumours they were competing, Microsoft has never admitted that. Main reason linq to sql was so quickly adopted is that EF 1 was crap and very incomplete. No debate from me on that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep ok, looks like the double queryable is tripping it up. Only option is to either left join to Offices or do the following:

```
       Office mainOffice = Offices.First();
       return from pc in _context.CalendarEntries
               join o in Offices on pc.LocationId equals o.Id into offices
               from office in offices.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new ScheduleEntry
                          {
                              Id = pc.CalendarId,
                              StartDateTime = pc.StartDateTime ?? DateTime.MinValue,
                              EndDateTime = pc.EndDateTime ?? DateTime.MinValue,
                              Office = pc.LocationId == 0 ? mainOffice : office,
                          };
```

I'm assuming you didn't want to do that due to complaints about making it IEnumerable so you will need to join to the Offices queryable some how to tell EF how to string the queries together. Let x = y or value = value is looking for a constant which i guess makes sense.

Comment: I get the same "Unable to create a constant value of type ..." exception.

Comment: Looked deeper and edited suggestion. Sorry about sloppiness, but trying to answer my own Q and got caught up in this one :D

Comment: Thanks. I get the same error doing this...BUT if I get the main office Id upfront: var mainOfficeId = Offices.First().Id, then use that Id in a second join in the query, it works.... It's not ideal, but it works.

Comment: Thanks. Just to your point earlier though...not being able to do exactly what you have in your example above: pc.LocationId == 0 ? mainOffice : office where office is part of the query and mainOffice is a local variable has nothing to do with the data store or SQL server or anything except the way EF has implemented the projection component of their IQueryProvider. There's no reason your example shouldn't be able to work...but it doesn't.

Comment: Agreed. It's understandable they can't construct the whole object to pass in to the select results, but I do think they could do something at populate with pointers or something. Linq to sql comparisons aside, I share your frustration with runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

`First` executes query when expression tree is constructed so it tries passing `Office` as parameter to your query which cannot be done.

One way to replace `First` is calling `this.Offices.Take(1)`.

Comment: That also produces the same "Unable to create a constant value of type" error. Also - First does NOT execute the query when the expression tree is constructed if it's part of a larger expression tree. That is, in the original example I provided, it is created as a MethodCallExpression for the Method First...it is not executed directly at construction time.

Comment: @Jeff: I just tested `First` on another query and once I use it in subquery I get an exception: *The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.* So I still think that `First` cannot be used inside the query but `FirstOrDefault` can.

Comment: Good point!...but that is still a function of the EF provider, not the way expression trees are created. I just tried replacing the First() in my example with FirstOrDefault() and I still do get the same "Unable to create a constant value..." exception...

Comment: I'm still  surprised that `Take(1)` doesn't work - I successfully used it before instead of `First`. It looks like EF provider doesn't like the way how different result sets are combined in the query because generally your subquery should have to be executed for each record with `pc.LocationId == 0`.