# Can't think of query that solves this many to many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I've got this complex situation.
Created EF with "Model first" and here are my EF entities:

```
-Course Lecturer many to many relationship-

  Course               Lecturer  
------------      -------------------           Column IS_PROFESOR is bool      
  +ID                 +ID                       value that makes Lecturer:
  +NAME               +FIRSTNAME                true: Course Profesor 
-----------           +LASTNAME                 false: Course Asistent
-LECTURERS            +IS_PROFESOR
-----------       -------------------
                      -COURSES                  
                  -------------------
```

Now *-LECTURERS* and *-COURSES* are navigation properties. 
From this tables in database i need to query data and put them in some **Model** so i can get following **Course Index View**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Course     |   Professor      |    Assistants     |          Actions
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    course 1   | course professor |assistant 1      |     edit update delete
               |                  |assistant 2      |     edit update delete
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    course 2   | course professor |assistant 1      |     edit update delete
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    course 3   | course professor |assistant 1      |     edit update delete
               |                  |assistant 2      |     edit update delete
               |                  |assistant 3      |     edit update delete
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see i need query that will populate some new View Model in that way that it can distinct **Course Professor** from **Course Assistants** list.
Model will be (right?):

`public class CourseView

    {

    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }

    public string ProfessorName { get; set; }

    public List AssistantNames { get; set; } // Or it should be List of Assistants

    }`

No way i can think of some rational solution for this problem with my own skills, any help, reference or suggestion will mean a lot for me,thx for every second of looking at this.

Comment: You might want to rethink your db design as it could allow more than one professor for a course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to redo your EF entities.  Right now you are saying that each course has multiple lecturers and a lecturer is either a professor or an assistant.  But your course index view seems to indicate that each course should have one professor and multiple assistants.  You also are indicating that a lecturer can only be a professor or an assistant.  I would first make sure that a professor of one course cannot be the assistant of another first.  If that is the case then I would create a separate table (or entity) for professors and assistants.  Make each course have one professor and multiple assistants.  On the other hand if professors can be assistants then you need to remove the professor designation from the lecturer and build it into the relationship to the courses by having each course have one lecturer that is the professor and a list of lecturers that are the assistants.

However if you want to continue with your current setup you should be able to populate your desired view with something like this

```
var courseViews = from c in db.Courses
                  select new CourseView()
                  {
                      CourseID = c.ID,
                      ProfessorName = (from l in c.Leturers 
                                       where l.Is_Professor 
                                       select l.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
                      AssistantNames = (from l in c.Leturers 
                                        where !l.Is_Professor 
                                        select l.Name).ToList()
                  };
```

Comment: That `FirstOrDefault` will make a trouble. I would try `Take(1)` instead.

Comment: @Ladislav How so?  Does EF not handle FirstOrDefault?  I personally have never tried it with EF.  Also a Take would result in a IQueryable instead of a string.

Comment: It indeed handles `FirstOrDefault` but `FirstOrDefault` triggers the query execution. There was another related question today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165425/entity-framework-complex-linq-support where calling `First` inside the query was source of the problem.

Comment: @Ladislav  Interesting.  I guess they'll have to try it out to see what works.  Redoing the design would of course remove the need for the FirstOrDefault.

Comment: I just made some test and `FirstOrDefault` will probably work because it behaves differently then `First`.

Comment: Thank you for everything guys,however i'm still fighting with test of representing assistant names in View. Just cant menage represent names in foreach() loop. juharr mentioned IQueriable.  What should be of this type?

Comment: @streetspirit  You should open a new question to give us the details of what new problems you are experiencing.

Comment: @juharr @Ladislav Right, thx for the lesson, it is priceless. I was quite stuck with this but now i can see the forest.