# LINQ to Entity Framework many to many with list of strings

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

This question is continuation from:
[Can't think of query that solves this many to many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167865/cant-think-of-query-that-solves-this-many-to-many)

This LINQ query is recommended to me by user @juharr, i just added string concatenation in purpose of grouping first and last name into full name.

```
var courseViews = from c in db.Courses  
                  select new CourseView()  
                  {  
                      CourseID = c.ID,  
                      ProfessorName = (from l in c.Leturers   
                                       where l.Is_Professor   
                                       select l.LastName+" "+l.FirstName).FirstOrDefault(),  
                      AssistantNames = (from l in c.Leturers   
                                        where !l.Is_Professor   
                                        select l.LastName+" "+l.FirstName)
                                        .ToList()   //hmmm problem
                  };
```

ModelView that i used is another possible cause of problems:

```
public class CourseView
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }
        public string ProfessorName { get; set; }
        public List AssistantNames { get; set; }
    }
```

Hmm List of strings for Assistant names problematic isn't it?
At the end of my stupidity, in **View** i looped through this list with `@foreach(var s in item.AssistantNames){@s}`
@Ladislav suggested using `IQueryable` instead of string,how where?

For solution that i made so far i get following **error**:

*LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] ToList[String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.*

Need help!

Comment: `public List AssistantNames { get; set; }` could be `public List<string>  AssistantNames { get; set; }`

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `ToList()` call and then change the Assistants property to this:

```
public IQueryable AssistantNames { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```
var courseViews = from c in db.Courses
                  let assistantsList =  (from l in c.Leturers   
                                        where !l.Is_Professor   
                                        select l.LastName+" "+l.FirstName).ToList()   
                  select new CourseView()  
                  {  
                      CourseID = c.ID,  
                      ProfessorName = (from l in c.Leturers   
                                       where l.Is_Professor   
                                       select l.LastName+" "+l.FirstName).FirstOrDefault(),  
                      AssistantNames =  assistantsList
                  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be, since you are materializing all courses anyway to split the query in two parts, the first one materializes the data, the second one uses it to create the course views (this is now a Linq to Objects query):

```
var courses = (from c in db.Courses 
               select new { c.ID, Leturers = c.Leturers.ToList() }).ToList();

var courseViews = from c in courses 
                  select new CourseView()  
                  {  
                      CourseID = c.ID,  
                      ProfessorName = (from l in c.Leturers   
                                       where l.Is_Professor   
                                       select l.LastName+" "+l.FirstName).FirstOrDefault(),  
                      AssistantNames = (from l in c.Leturers   
                                        where !l.Is_Professor   
                                        select l.LastName+" "+l.FirstName)
                                        .ToList()  
                  };
```